# Check how much memory PHP array take

Tags: php, memory

Is there any simple way to check how much memory does some array take?

Like I've got some 10k rows array and need to know how much MB/KB it takes for server to remember it inside some `$arr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// how much memory are you using before building your array
$baseMemory = memory_get_usage(false);
// create your array
$a = array('A',1,'B',2);
// how much memory are you using now the array is built
$finalMemory = memory_get_usage(false);
// the difference is a pretty close approximation
$arrayMemory = $finalMemory - $baseMemory;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the following function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php